# Cordova background geolcation not working

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i'm working device tracking example..

i tried below plugin....
**https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt**

**this controller code**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {

  var bgGeo = window.BackgroundGeolocation;
  console.log(bgGeo);
  alert(JSON.stringify(bgGeo));
})
```

This code throw error : "bgGeo is undefined..!!";

after try below link..

https://github.com/rishantagarwal/CordovaBackgroundGeolocationStartingUpExample

This getting **Backgroundgeolocation : invalid license**

plse help me

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Because I'm also getting to the same issue. But couldn't find any solution for it. Please share your solution if you resolved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Balakumaran: I'm trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation
As you provided free key. Where should i use this plugin in my given plugin. Thanks again dear